# What does "use social media to the chagrin of their administrators" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I learned the sentence in bold from the transcript of a [podcast](http://www.scientificamerican.com/podcast/episode.cfm?id=journal-article-tweets-may-predict-12-02-17) in 60-Second Science:

> Eysenbach tracked more than 4200 tweets that cited 286 articles in his
>   own journal. Three quarters of articles that got tweeted a lot (or, to
>   use the study’s nomenclature, had a lot of tweetations) turned out to
>   get a lot of citations. Only 7 percent of poorly tweeted pieces wound
>   up highly cited. As the article notes: "Social media activity either
>   increases citations or reflects the underlying qualities of the
>   article that also predict citations." **But I predict that young
>   researchers *who use social media to the chagrin of their
>   administrators* will cite this journal article. Or tweet about it.**

I don't understand what is the meaning of "*use social media to the chagrin of their administrators*". Is there a phrase of the pattern "use something to something"?

Comment: Younger researchers use social media to tweet about their articles. Old-fashioned research administrators do not appreciate these new-fangled tweetations. So the researchers are driving their administrators nuts.

Comment: I think it may be the writer simply meant *"in defiance of their [I.T.] administrators"*. But whatever - a more common phrasing with exactly the same meaning is *"[much] to the **dismay** of..."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use:

> *to the* + emotion + *of* + somebody

or

> *to* + possessive determiner + emotion

to show somebody's emotional response to the sentence.  E.g.

> To the delight of the spectators, he went on to score another goal.
>
> Our neighbour is learning to play the drums, much to our annoyance.

So, in your example sentence, administrators feel chagrin that young people use social media.  It is these young people who will cite the journal article.

Comment: *our* is a ***possessive determiner***; *ours* is a genitive/possessive pronoun.  Very different things.

Answer (score 0):

cha·grin  (sh-grn)
 A keen feeling of mental unease, as of annoyance or embarrassment

"to the chagrin of" means to cause annoyance or embarassment to

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can understand the meaning of "chagrin". The problem is that I don't know what's the meaning of the phrase "use social media to the chagrin of their administrators".

Comment: *Chagrin* is pronounced   /ʃəˈgrɪn/.

Comment: @tchrist - I copied the defn from a US dictionary

Answer (score 0):

> ... young researchers who use social media, to the chagrin of their administrators will cite this journal article.
>   ... young researchers who use social media to the chagrin of their administrators, will cite this journal article.

Above, I added commas to part of the quote in two different ways.  The two forms may be recast somewhat as follows:

> ... young researchers who use social media will cite this journal article to the chagrin of their administrators.
>   ... young researchers who will cite this journal article use social media to the chagrin of their administrators.

Unfortunately the original quote does not have commas in it.  The writer could have intended either meaning; it supports both equally well (or equally badly, for that matter).  Absent a comma, syntactic patterns don't reveal which meaning was intended.